# How Do I need to configure Maven when already it is present in eclipse as plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to configure Maven on system variable when I already have Maven as a plugin in my eclipse

Comment: If you like to use maven from command line you need to install it first. Nothing to do with Eclipse. http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 0):

You could download the Maven3 binaries and extract into a directory. Your environment variable must have `M2_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` before you can use the Maven in command line.

`M2_HOME` is the path to your Maven installation folder.

`JAVA_HOME` is the path to your Java installation folder.

To confirm things are in place, I would suggest running the command: `mvn --version`.

### Update

Adding `%M2_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` will allow Maven to execute commands through command prompt as suggested by @khmarbaise.

Please update us with your issues.

Comment: Don't use M2_HOME. Simply put the folder of the Maven distribution into PATH and set JAVA_HOME that's it.